# Making a (Java) class extend observable in WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, ant, wsdl, observable

I have created a Webservice containing a WSDL. I create a Jar file containing the Java classes from this Webservice with an ANT script. Then I use this jar in my Java-Application as my basic model classes. Works perfectly fine, without touching the jar itself. I use the Apache CXF Framework (Thanks @Mark O'Connor)

But now, i want to implement the Observer pattern with my basic model classes. They should be observable by my other (custom) Java View Classes. Unfortunately, they don't extend Observable and because they are already in a class hirarchy, they will never do...

I don't want to fiddle around in my generated JAR file, containing the basic model classes, because this jar will always be auto-generated. There I could easily make the basic model class extend Observable...

So here is my Question: Can I define something in the WSDL or in my ANT Script to make them extend Observable automatically? I suppose not. But maybe one of you brainiacs has an idea. How do you make complex model classes (that already extend something) observable?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You made no reference to the web services framework you are using... Could be Axis2, CXF, Metro, etc.....

Comment: @Mark O'Connor Sorry, I forgot that. Edited above... Its Apache CXF!

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this issue, by misusing the ActionListener, that is attached to the view. The AL now extends Observable and fires the hasChanged() stuff itself, after manipulating the model. This is clearly NOT, what the Observer pattern is all about, rather than a nasty workaround. Because now the model can be changed by a different AL, without invoking the notifyObservers Mehtod. But in my case, it works.

Any better ideas?